# Indivisiblity of quarks

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

I have been researching the Standard Model of Particle Physics recently. According to the model, quarks are indivisible. Does this mean that quarks cannot be divided, or does it mean that if we were to divide them, we would be left with nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The former](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle), although [maybe we're wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon). [It wouldn't be the first time](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2014-11-25).

Comment: Just for the cartoon I'd vote this up.

Comment: @StephenG If you press the red button you get a bonus panel, namely a Feynman diagram.